# Generate the Different IV for every Time in RSA encryption

Tags: go, encryption, rsa

The generated IV is correct or not every time it will give me some random output
or is their any other way to do this.

```
ciphertext := make([]byte, aes.BlockSize+len(plaintext))
    iv := ciphertext[:aes.BlockSize]
    iv = key[:aes.BlockSize]
    if _, err := io.ReadFull(rand.Reader, iv); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    log.Println("IV Simple String:", string(iv))
```

Give some random result like

```
��=�      49k�Ɓ�ʲ��
```

Can't even understand this !!!

Comment: try format iv by `fmt.Sprintf("%x", iv)`

Comment: Thanks for your response it seems to good in that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make it human readable, you've got couple options:

- base64

  base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(iv)
- Hex

  hex.EncodeToString(iv)

and so on.